# how to run monkeytalk recorded scripts in multiple times?

Tags: automated-testing, android, eclipse, monkeytalk

We are using eclipse luna 4.4.1, adb is installed on linux system to test android app.

I have recorded a monkeytalk script. So my question is how to run that monkeytalk recorded script in 500 times. But in every loop the value of input data should be change(Validation stuff).
For example : I recorded sign up account. So that need to run it 500 times to create 500 diffrent account.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the MonkeyLab tests from the commandline: http://www.cloudmonkeymobile.com/monkeytalk-documentation/monkeytalk-faq#1.13

If you are a able to run a single test from the command line then wrap it around a [bash script that loops](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-7.html) 500 times.

Example bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash 
COUNTER=0
while [  $COUNTER -lt 500 ]; do
  java -jar monkeytalk-runner.jar -agent iOS yourtestfilename.mt
  let COUNTER=COUNTER+1 
done
```

**Data Driven**:

Seems MonkeyTalk supports looping with CSV files. It will loop the test-script for each line in the CSV file. See the documentation here: https://www.cloudmonkeymobile.com/monkeytalk-documentation/monkeytalk-user-guide/data-driving-scripts

Comment: will you please provide me proper steps if possible? It will be more helpful.
thanks anyways.

Comment: Added example script, but if that does not get you any further I suggest you contact your local developers to assist you running the tests from the command-line and looping it.

Comment: Thnaks for quick reply, i will try nd let you know.

Comment: Hi Niels van Reijmersdal, i tried with the bash script and its working, thanks for your answer. But i have one more question- how to run the script as a data driven? 
For Example: I have one recorded monkeytalk script for login, created one bash script to run 100 times.
But it should login for 100 diffrent users which already created.
So what should i do?

Comment: https://www.cloudmonkeymobile.com/monkeytalk-documentation/monkeytalk-user-guide/data-driving-scripts